# Correct verb for "removal" of a chess piece by opponent's action

Tags: verbs

What is the correct verb to convey the meaning of expelling or removal of a chess piece, which is done by your opponent's action; i.e. when he or she moves one of his pieces to a square where one of your pieces is located?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to  https://chess.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user5768790 it's a perfectly acceptable English language question, otherwise, why did you answer it in the first place? This question would be closed immediately on SE Chess for lack of research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - I answered because I misunderstood. Only those who play and are close to chess/checkers  circles can tell you if capture or take is more commonly used. That’s what OP ultimately wants to know. It is sort of jargon usage OP is looking for.

Comment: I aways considered chess to be a rather silent game... @user5768790 I'm sure the rules of chess are online, accessible to all, and the term for kidnapping an opponent's piece is used. General reference might be a better reason for closing the question. Might... not saying it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common alternative to *capture* (suggested by user5768790) for the expelling or removing from the board of an opponent's piece is *take*:

> - Why does white not *take* on e5 in the Kings Indian Defense?
> - The white queen can move to one of the marked squares, or *take* one of the
>     black rooks.
> - The bishop can *take* any other piece on the board that
>     is within its bounds of movement.
> - When a pawn does not *take*, it moves one square straight forward.

Comment: Any source for that? Is that more informal than "capture"?

Comment: @deLock. The sentences above are from a Google search on "_chess + take_". _Take_ is both more common and more informal than _capture_. "_Chess + 'captures on'_": 652.000 results - "_Chess + 'takes on'_": 31.800.000 results. I have played chess for many years and I don't think I have ever used the verb _capture_ in  discussions with my opponent  after the game. It's always something like: _Why didn't you take the knight? I should have taken the pawn when I had the chance._

Comment: I’d say that “capture” is the  term you’ll most likely  find in books and sites which discuss chess rules. Take is commonly   used by players as a more informal term.

Answer (score 1):

The term is ***[capture:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess)***

> A move by a pawn or piece that removes from the board the opponent’s pawn or piece. The capturing piece then occupies the square of the captured piece (except in the case of a capture that is done [en passant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant)).

(Wikipedia)

***[Capturing:](https://www.thespruce.com/illustrated-guide-to-chess-pieces-611547)***

> Like most pieces, the rook cannot jump over other pieces. However, it can land on a square occupied by an opponent’s piece, removing that piece from the board. ***This is known as capturing a piece. All pieces are capable of capturing in this manner.***
>
> In the diagram above, the rook can move to any of the squares marked with a dot. It can also capture the black bishop on g4 by moving to that square. It may not move onto or through the squares occupied by the white pawns.

[image]

(www.thespruce.com)

Comment: Can "capture" be used in other games with pieces and squares (other than chess)? Or would "take" be more common?

Comment: @deLock - it is used also in Checkers for instance: *A piece making a capturing move (a jump) leaps over one of the opponent's pieces, landing in a straight diagonal line on the other side. Only one piece may be captured in a single jump; however, multiple jumps are allowed during a single turn.* https://www.thespruce.com/play-checkers-using-standard-rules-409287

Comment: @deLock - one of the meanings of *to take* is *to capture*. That’s why it is used in chess, checkers and other similar games, you may ask also here to have a more spot on answer. https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/is-capturing-a-piece-while-castling-legal